# Sum rows by hour including empty hours?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, grouping, interpolation

So basically I need to generate a report on an hour by hour bases of the lat 48 hours.
For any empty hours I want to return 0 for `total_videos` and `time_in_seconds`.

But my attempt doesn't seem to be returning the empty rows, instead I am getting:

```
period                   total_videos  time_in_seconds  
Apr 10th 14 00:00-00:59  11            406.00           
Apr 10th 14 02:00-02:59  5             70.00            
Apr 10th 14 03:00-03:59  10            110.00           
Apr 10th 14 06:00-06:59  1             85.40            
Apr 10th 14 07:00-07:59  4             103.00           
Apr 10th 14 08:00-08:59  5             292.44           
Apr 10th 14 12:00-12:59  1             2258.52          
Apr 10th 14 21:00-21:59  5             5189.33          
Apr 10th 14 22:00-22:59  1             182.39           
Apr 10th 14 23:00-23:59  9             119.16           
Apr 11th 14 03:00-03:59  1             2039.13
```

Here is the query.

```
#Create a table of all 24 hours
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hours;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE hours (`hour` INT);
INSERT INTO hours (`hour`) VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23);

#Create a table that contains todays date, yesterdays date, and the day before (48 hours)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dates;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dates (`date` DATE);
INSERT INTO dates(`date`) VALUES (DATE(NOW())), (DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)), (DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR));

SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(v.`created_at`,'%b %D %y %H:00-%H:59') AS period,
COUNT(v.created_at) AS `total_videos`,
SUM(v.duration) AS `time_in_seconds`
 FROM videos AS v
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN hours AS h ON HOUR(v.`created_at`) = h.hour
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN dates AS d ON DATE(v.`created_at`) = d.date
  WHERE v.created_at IS NULL OR DATE(v.created_at) >= (SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
 GROUP BY d.date, h.hour
 ORDER BY d.date, h.hour ASC;
```

Comment: You don't need to create the temporary tables is better to generate something using select row_number() from sys.objects or similar. I'd look at doing a simpler query first as the problem looks to be in the outer join-maybe left outer join.

Answer (score 0):

I admit I don't find the flaw in your statement. It is rare to see criteria on the outer joined table (which is Videos in your case) appear in the where clause. And when people do this, they often forget about the outer joined records there. But you do not. You explicitly check for null, so I don't see what's wrong with it.

You know that the select statement would return completely empty lines for the gaps, yes? All values shown in the result list are from Videos. But well, these empty lines should be shown. Strange.

You may want to try this statement which uses left joins that are more common and thus easier to read for most of us:

```
SELECT 
  d.date, 
  h.hour,
  DATE_FORMAT(v.created_at,'%b %D %y %H:00-%H:59') AS period,
  COUNT(v.created_at) AS total_videos,
  SUM(v.duration) AS time_in_seconds
FROM hours as h
CROSS JOIN dates d
LEFT JOIN videos AS v ON DATE(v.created_at) = d.date AND HOUR(v.created_at) = h.hour
WHERE v.created_at IS NULL OR 
GROUP BY d.date, h.hour
ORDER BY d.date, h.hour;
```

I've added d.date and h.hour to the result columns for the testing purpose. Does this statement work?